# Animation in ListViews

Tags: winjs

I am designing an app which has a page that has tow list views. Lets call them "MainListView" and "SecondaryListView". the two list views are placed side by side ("MainListView" is on left and "SecondaryListView" is on right). The data in these two lists is a parent child data from a Web API.

Scenario 1:

The flow is like below:

1. When page is initialized initial parent data is present in  "SecondaryListView" (level 1 data).

2.User clicks one item in the "SecondaryListView". The Data clicked is moved to "MainListView" and the "SecondaryListView" now gets updated by the child o selected item.

1. This sequence goes on till the last child is reached.

Scenario 2:

Lets say the user has gone to 5th level. The 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th level selected data is there in "MainListView" and "SecondaryListView" has the childrens of 5th selected data.

1. Now users selects the 2nd level selected data in "MainListView".
2. The 3rd, 4th, 5th level data gets deleted from "MainListView" and the "SecondaryListView" gets filled with children of 2nd level.

My requirement is that I need to add some animation. Here is the animation that is desired:

1. In Scenario 1 when user selects one item from "SecondaryListView" the item to slide towards the "MainListView" and get added at bottom of the list. Currently it is just getting added. There is no slide animation.
2. In Scenario  2 when user selects one item from "MainListView", the other elements that gets deleted (in example 3rd, 4th, 5th) should slide down the list and disappear. Currently the sliding and deletion animation is not getting achieved.

Both my list use binding for data and use template. The functionality is fully working baring the animation that is desired. Currently if I change the binding data the functionality works but the animation is something I am not able to get it working.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

- Girija

Comment: This is going to be pretty hard. The list view just don't support the level of customization you want. I suspect that your 'best' solution is going to be figuring out the screen-relative start & end positions, and then using translate animations/transitions to move a fake postion: absolute looks-the-same-but-isn't element from one position to the other.